# Can't boot some ISOs with 2th Gen in Hyper-V

Tags: iso-image, hyper-v

I have problem with booting some kinds of ISOs (preferble Windows ISOs) in 2th Gen mode of Hyper-V. With 1th Gen no problems. But when I try to create and boot new VM from this ISOs I face with this problem

[image: screenshot]

Secure boot is disabled.
Use only x64 ISO images. Like Windows10_1809_x64, WindowsServer2016_x64.

Answer (score -1):

I found solution for this case. The problem was with SCSI-controller. When I create new VM I shouldn't add and attach ISO with OS. I should attach it later when VM was create. And choose 2th or (more)th interface in SCSI(which isn't in use). Other things doesn't matter. I don't know why it is happend. Maybe, it is VMBus's specifica of work.